# Creating random colors (System.Drawing.Color)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am tring to create random drawing colors. There is an error. Could you help me about this code.

```
        private Random random;

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            random = new Random();
        }

        private Color GetRandomColor()
        {
            return Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0,255),random.Next(0,255));
        // The error is here
        }  

        public SolidBrush brushGet()
        {
            SolidBrush oBrush = new SolidBrush(GetRandomColor());
            return oBrush;
        }
```

Comment: Not that it isn't fun to guess, but please do us a favour and tell us what the error is.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException

Comment: That's a start. On what line / in what method?

Comment: Likely that your Random isn't being initialized before call to GetRandomColor. Use private Random random = new Random();

Comment: @nonnb Good call. Might also point out that you may as well mark the field `static`, so it's initialized the first time the class is referenced, and the same RNG instance is used throughout the program. And then post your comment as an answer. :)

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that `random.Next(lower, upper)` may return the lower bound but never returns the upper bound. It is implemented such that it returns a number X where `lower <= x < upper`.This means there are a few colours, including pure white (255,255,255) that your code will never generate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any problems with the above code, other than the Random object not being initialized before it is called to. There is also absolutely no need to initialize it in the Load event of the form; it can be done right when it's declared:

```
private static readonly Random Random = new Random();
```

Personally I'd not declare it on local scope, as far as I know you end up with the same value every time if you go about it that way. I also personally don't see the need of overcomplicating things; generating random numbers everytime and using the `Color.FromAgb()` method you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

This Worked for me (at the GetRandomColor):

```
Random random = new Random();
return Color.FromArgb((byte)random.Next(0, 255), (byte)random.Next(0, 255), (byte)random.Next(0, 255));
```

Comment: It should be FromArgb ,notFromRgb ( Visual Studio 2015)

Comment: Thx. Editing Now!

Answer (score 2):

```
    private Color color;
    private int b;
    public Color Random()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        b = r.Next(1, 5);
        switch (b)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    color = Color.Red;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                {
                    color = Color.Blue;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                {
                    color = Color.Green;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                {
                    color = Color.Yellow;
                }
                break;
        }

        return color;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I **guess** `brushGet` gets called before `MainForm_Load` could have created `random`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here

```
return Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0,255), random.Next(0,255), random.Next(0,255));
```

You need to cast `random.Next(0, 255)` doing this `(byte)random.Next(0, 255)`,
and `FromArgb` needs 4 parameters.

Comment: `Color.FromArgb` has had an overload that accepts 3 int parameters for R, G and B since the dawn of time/.NET 1.1

Answer (score 1):

Generating 3 random numbers and calculating the color integer can be avoided:

```
static Random random = new Random();

Color GetRandomColor() { return Color.FromArgb(unchecked(random.Next() | 255 << 24)); }

Color GetRandomKnownColor() {
    return Color.FromKnownColor((KnownColor)random.Next((int)KnownColor.YellowGreen) + 1); }
```

The `unchecked | 255 << 24` part is used to avoid transparent colors.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {    
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ovalShape1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            ovalShape1.BackStyle = BackStyle.Opaque;

            random = new Random();

            ovalShape1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255));

         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: A little explanation would boost the quality of your answer.